# C# How to add string variables with values to the any System.Collections class and retrieve them

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

So I have a slightly interesting problem right here. What I'm trying to achieve is to add between **1000** to **2000** string variables to the list and later compare them with another strings. So far I can achieve this by using below code:

```
var list = new List<string>();
var item_1 = "USA";
var item_2 = "Canada";
var item_3 = "Cuba";
...................
var item_N = "Country_N";
list.Add(item_1);
list.Add(item_2);
list.Add(item_3);
.................
list.Add(item_N);
```

And comparing them with another strings looks like below (using FluentAssertions class):

```
list[0].Should().Match(stringToCompare_1);
list[1].Should().Match(stringToCompare_2);
list[2].Should().Match(stringToCompare_3);
```

The biggest problem that I see here is it's sort of hard to memorize what string was added to a particular index of the list (unstoppable scrolling between the code is boring). My question: is there any more elegant way to handle this situation? Something that might look like below (List class method **ValueOf** is fictional):

```
var list = new List<string>();
var item_1_USA = "USA";
var item_2_Canada = "Canada";
var item_3_Cuba = "Cuba";
list.ValueOf(item_1_USA).Should().Match(stringToCompare_1);
list.ValueOf(item_1_Canada).Should().Match(stringToCompare_2);
list.ValueOf(item_1_Cuba).Should().Match(stringToCompare_3);
```

As many suggested (including @Postlagerkarte) to edit the question to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. I'm testing the web app, and while going through every step of this application (imagine booking engine), I need to capture and store different info (like user's First Name, Last Name, Email Address, Phone Number, etc). The amount of the captured info can sometimes exceed 2000 items. Currently I'm using data structure **List**. Later, at the final step of my application, I need to compare my stored values with what ever present on this final page. For instance: user's first name, that was captured on Step 2 of the booking engine must match with value on final step. **List** **Contains** method won't be suitable here as it can validate incorrect information. Accessing the values using `list[0]....list[N]` is very inconvenient, as I can forget what exactly was stored at that index. I'm solving it now by scrolling through the code to return back. Any wise navigation is appreciated.

Comment: Would the index always match?  (i.e item_1 should compare with stringToCompare_1).  Why do you need the list at all if you are just comparing the individual variables?  Why are you looking for a more "elegant" solution when you have potentially thousands of individual variables?

Comment: That is the problem that indexes won't always match...

Comment: I'd suggest clarifying your question, I'm having a really hard time understanding what you need.

Comment: Take a look at the Dictionary data structure. It allows key value pairs and might be what you are looking for. http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary   https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: If indexes don’t match then simply checking if it contains the value should be enough

Comment: +1 for clarification. Please explain more about the reason behind your action. I can't figure out why the hell you are doing what you are doing.

Comment: Also a bit confused by exactly what you want, where are the values which you are comparing the values of the item list to coming from, are they all individual strings or do you want to essentially compare two lists lista[0] = listb[0] etc?

Comment: @d219 I do apologize for this confusion. The values that I'm comparing are located at the final step of my application. So basically imagine train, where you are walking from the beginning railway carriage to the head of the train, and there are total 10 those carriages. You are picking up different items in different carriages, and till you get to the head of the train you've gathered 2000 items. Now, in the final carriage, there should be exact amount of items as you've gathered, and you have to validate that each item in present at the final carriage. Hopefully this clears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, string>` for this. The key of each value would be a field or info identifier: userFirstName, userAge, etc. As you process data you add it to your dictionary with whatever value you are reading.

When validating, you look up the stored value with the field identifier and compare it to whatever data shows upon your last page.

You can also consider using an enumeration as your key instead of string although if you avoid magic strings literals and use constants you should be ok.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I can use var items = new Dictionary<string, string>(). items.Add("First Name", "There will be user's first name here"). And when I do Console.WriteLine(items["FirstName"]); it exactly prints the value of this key. Thanks for the right navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the `Contains()` method saying

```
list.Contains(stringToCompare_1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My actual requirement is to validate against every item on the page, not just that list contains a value.